# How to return TimeSpan without formatting?

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(10,130,10);
```

after the execution of above line, normally the value of `timeSpan` is formatted as `12:10:10`

Is there any chance can I get value as `10:130:10` (i.e., without formatting)? I need it for a critical situation.

Comment: _"I need it for a critical situation."_ - that sounds really important but doesn't really help your question. Have you considered writing your own class with the three properties you require?

Comment: CodeCaster i'll try ..thanks,i just wanted to know that, is there any already defined possibilities for my requirement..now i'm clear with Soner's answer.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way you get `10:130:10`  after you define your `TimeSpan` constructor. And there is no reason to keep them becuase 10 hours + 130 minutes + 10 seconds is equal to `12:10:10` as we all know. It is a time interval, not keeps time components separately.

From [`TimeSpan(Int32, Int32, Int32)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The specified hours, minutes, and seconds are converted to ticks, **and
>   that value initializes this instance**.

Let's look at how this contructor defined;

```
public TimeSpan(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    _ticks = TimeToTicks(hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

And this is how `TimeToTicks` methods implemented;

```
internal static long TimeToTicks(int hour, int minute, int second)
{
    long totalSeconds = (long)hour * 3600 + (long)minute * 60 + (long)second;
    if (totalSeconds > MaxSeconds || totalSeconds < MinSeconds)
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(null, Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_TimeSpanTooLong"));
    return totalSeconds * TicksPerSecond;
}
```

As you can see, this method doesn't keep constructor parameters (`hours`, `minute` or `second`). It just calculate `totalseconds` from `hours * 3600 + minute * 60 + second` value.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeSpan` doesn't work like that.  It represents an elapsed duration of time, not individual time components.  See [Soner's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22576433) for further details.

If you are looking to keep "10 hours, 130 minutes, 10 seconds" as separate information, then you should consider the [ISO-8601 duration format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).  As a string, that value would look like `"PT10H130M10S"`.

In .NET, you can use the `Period` type from the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library to work with these sort of values.

To create a single part period, you can take advantage of simple factory methods like `Period.FromMonths(3)`.  But to create a multi-part period, you will need to do one of the following approaches:

- You can use a `PeriodBuilder` to build a period from individual variables:

  ```
  PeriodBuilder builder = new PeriodBuilder();
  builder.Hours = 10;
  builder.Minutes = 130;
  builder.Seconds = 10;

  Period period = builder.Build();
  string s = period.ToString();

  Debug.WriteLine(s); // "PT10H130M10S"
  ```
- You can parse a period from an ISO-8601 duration string, using a `PeriodPattern`.  In particular, the `RoundtripPattern` shown below will retain the parts exactly as they were originally supplied:

  ```
  string s = "PT10H130M10S";
  PeriodPattern pattern = PeriodPattern.RoundtripPattern;
  ParseResult<Period> result = pattern.Parse(s);
  if (result.Success)
  {
      Period p = result.Value;

      Debug.WriteLine(p.Hours);   // 10
      Debug.WriteLine(p.Minutes); // 130
      Debug.WriteLine(p.Seconds); // 10
  }
  ```

Comment: That's nice to know Matt. In such a case `Period.FromHours` returns `10` and `Period.FromMinutes` returns `130` values? And how to pass `"PT10H130M10S"` string in `Period` class? I couldn't find any `Period` constructor takes `string` as a parameter on documentation of Noda Time.

Comment: @SonerGönül - See update for some example usage of a multi-part `Period`.  Cheers!